# Docker container deployment fails in azure web app

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have deployed the simple Hello-world docker image in azure web app for testing as my original application is failing with the similar issue. The hello-world image will download successfully but fail to start with below error:
INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container container123445_0_2ec54b26 for site container123445
ERROR - Container container123445_0_2ec54b26 for site container123445 has exited, failing site start
ERROR - Container container123445_0_2ec54b26 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See containerlogs for debugging.
INFO  - Stoping site container123445 because it failed during startup.
When I browse the webapp URL, it gives me "application error" page. Its very simple deployment, but failing.

Comment: Hi, can you show the logs of te container? Solving this problem requires you to provide specific error information.:)